# Excel VSTO-Template PowerQuery

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

So I made a Excel VSTO-Template project using visual studio 2019. In this project I want to add a PowerQuery (in user interface I made Data -> New Blank Power Query -> Made what I need) and then I go in Advanced Editor to see the query and c/c. So I have something like this :

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("http://localhost:53626/tables/invoice", [Headers=[#"ApiKey"=GetValue("ApiKey")]])),
#"Converti en table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
#"Column1 développé" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converti en table", "Column1", {"dueDate", "invoiceDate", "paymentStatus", "paymentDate", "printDate", "lastRemindedDate", "lastRemindedLevel", "balance", "totalDue", "organizationNodeId", "internalNumber"}, {"dueDate", "invoiceDate", "paymentStatus", "paymentDate", "printDate", "lastRemindedDate", "lastRemindedLevel", "balance", "totalDue", "organizationNodeId", "internalNumber"}),
#"totalDue développé" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Column1 développé", "totalDue", {"incl", "excl", "vat"}, {"totalDue.incl", "totalDue.excl", "totalDue.vat"}),
#"Lignes filtrées" = Table.SelectRows(#"totalDue développé", each true)
in
#"Lignes filtrées"
```

But now I want to add it using C# code, but I can't figure out how to do it, can you help me do this?
I know there is a Connections property in the workbook and that I should use [Add2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.connections.add2?view=excel-pia) to add a connection, but I can't find any clue on how to format the ConnectionString and CommandText parameter

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The required properties are not available in the type library but is available through late binding (i.e. IDispatch). You can use the "dynamic" keyword in C# to perform late binding with the caveats that compile time error checking and code completion won't work. See code below. The Interop Excel objects are aliased with "using Excelxxx = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.xxx"). "workbook" is a strongly typed Interop Workbook object and "queryText" is the M/Power Query formula in a string.

```
       //  add query
        dynamic workbook2 = workbook;
        dynamic queries = workbook2.Queries;
        dynamic query = queries.Add("ODataQuery-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss"), queryText, "");

        // add sheet with query
        ExcelSheet sheet = workbook.Sheets.Add();

        ExcelListObject listObject = sheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType: 0, Source: "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=" + query.Name, Destination: sheet.Range["$A$1"]);

        listObject.QueryTable.CommandType = XlCmdType.xlCmdDefault;
        listObject.QueryTable.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + query.Name + "]";
        listObject.QueryTable.RowNumbers = false;
        listObject.QueryTable.FillAdjacentFormulas = false;
        listObject.QueryTable.PreserveFormatting = true;
        listObject.QueryTable.RefreshOnFileOpen = false;
        listObject.QueryTable.BackgroundQuery = true;
        listObject.QueryTable.RefreshStyle = XlCellInsertionMode.xlOverwriteCells;
        listObject.QueryTable.SavePassword = false;
        listObject.QueryTable.SaveData = true;
        listObject.QueryTable.AdjustColumnWidth = true;
        listObject.QueryTable.RefreshPeriod = 0;
        listObject.QueryTable.PreserveColumnInfo = false;

        listObject.QueryTable.Refresh(true);
```

Comment: This works well with VSTO without the need for any additional references.

Answer (score 0):

Since I basically face the same dilemma as the poster this is the only work-around I know for now. 
You also need to add the COM-reference "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3"

And it's ugly:

```
var newStandardModule = ((Excel.Workbook)this.Application.ActiveWorkbook).VBProject.VBComponents.Add(Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);

var codeModule = newStandardModule.CodeModule;

// add vba code to module
var lineNum = codeModule.CountOfLines + 1;
var macroName = "addQuery";
var codeText = "Public Sub " + macroName + "()" + "\r\n";
// codeText += "  MsgBox \"Hi from Excel\"" + "\r\n";



var m_text = "\"let\" _\r\n";
m_text += "& vbCrLf & \"Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(\"\"http://localhost:53626/tables/invoice\"\", [Headers =[#\"\"ApiKey\"\"=GetValue(\"\"ApiKey\"\")]])),\" _\r\n";
m_text += "& vbCrLf & \"#\"\"Converti en table\"\" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),\" _\r\n";
m_text += "& vbCrLf & \"#\"\"Column1 développé\"\" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#\"\"Converti en table\"\", \"\"Column1\"\", {\"\"dueDate\"\", \"\"invoiceDate\"\", \"\"paymentStatus\"\", \"\"paymentDate\"\", \"\"printDate\"\", \"\"lastRemindedDate\"\", \"\"lastRemindedLevel\"\", \"\"balance\"\", \"\"totalDue\"\", \"\"organizationNodeId\"\", \"\"internalNumber\"\"}, {\"\"dueDate\"\", \"\"invoiceDate\"\", \"\"paymentStatus\"\", \"\"paymentDate\"\", \"\"printDate\"\", \"\"lastRemindedDate\"\", \"\"lastRemindedLevel\"\", \"\"balance\"\", \"\"totalDue\"\", \"\"organizationNodeId\"\", \"\"internalNumber\"\"}),\" _\r\n";
m_text += "& vbCrLf & \"#\"\"totalDue développé\"\" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#\"\"Column1 développé\"\", \"\"totalDue\"\", {\"\"incl\"\", \"\"excl\"\", \"\"vat\"\"}, {\"\"totalDue.incl\"\", \"\"totalDue.excl\"\", \"\"totalDue.vat\"\"}),\" _\r\n";
m_text += "& vbCrLf & \"#\"\"Lignes filtrées\"\" = Table.SelectRows(#\"\"totalDue développé\"\", each true)\" _\r\n";
m_text += "& vbCrLf & \"in\" _\r\n";
m_text += "& vbCrLf & \"#\"\"Lignes filtrées\"\"\"";

codeText += "ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:=\"test\", Formula:=" + m_text + "\r\n";
codeText += "ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Add2 _\r\n";
codeText += "\"Query - test\", _\r\n";
codeText += "\"Connection to the 'test' query in the workbook.\", _\r\n";
codeText += "\"OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=test;Extended Properties=\" _\r\n";
codeText += ", \"\"\"test\"\"\", 6, True, False\r\n";

codeText += "End Sub";

codeModule.InsertLines(lineNum, codeText);

var macro = string.Format("{0}.{1}", newStandardModule.Name, macroName);
this.Application.Run(macro);
```